# Assembly loader confusing behaviour

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, vspackage, assembly-loading, assemblybinding

I am developing VS2012 Package (using SDK), which implements custom visual designer. The Solution contains a several projects. When I run my package in VS experimental instance, then try to open my custom visual designer, I get a following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Configuration
  FileName=VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
(...)
StackTrace:
       at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeImpl(String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.CreateInstanceRestricted[T](Type callingType, String typeString)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor(PropertyInfo info)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreateConfigurationPropertyFromAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInformation)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreatePropertyBagFromType(Type type)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.PropertiesFromType(Type type, ConfigurationPropertyCollection& result)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreateConfigurationPropertyFromAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInformation)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreatePropertyBagFromType(Type type)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.PropertiesFromType(Type type, ConfigurationPropertyCollection& result)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.get_Properties()
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.set_Item(String propertyName, Object value)
       at VisualDesigner.Configuration.XmlConfiguration.Element.FlowSection.set_Xmlns(String value) in c:\Users\wjarema\Repositories\VisualDesigner\src\Configuration\XmlConfiguration\Element\FlowSection.cs:line 20
```

It looks like assembly binding problem, so I decided to consult **Fusion Log Viewer** to get some additional info about assembly loader error.

What is strange, Fusion log says that when I try to open my visual designer, there are **four attempts** to load `VisualDesigner.Configuration` - **two times successfully, but also failed twice**:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-10-07 @ 15:43:48) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : VisualDesigner.Designer, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\WJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dev18A5.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
(...)
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/USERS/WJAREMA/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/11.0EXP/EXTENSIONS/FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE/1.0/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\USERS\WJAREMA\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\11.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE\1.0\VisualDesigner.Configuration.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\USERS\WJAREMA\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\11.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE\1.0\VisualDesigner.Configuration.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-10-07 @ 15:43:48) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : VisualDesigner.Designer, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\WJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dev18A5.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/USERS/WJAREMA/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/11.0EXP/EXTENSIONS/FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE/1.0/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\USERS\WJAREMA\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\11.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE\1.0\VisualDesigner.Configuration.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\USERS\WJAREMA\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\11.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\FLOW DESIGNER PACKAGE\1.0\VisualDesigner.Configuration.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-10-07 @ 15:43:48) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\WJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dev18A5.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2013-10-07 @ 15:43:48) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VisualDesigner.Configuration, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2639211081ade27
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\WJAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dev18A5.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/VisualDesigner.Configuration/VisualDesigner.Configuration.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

I have no idea why it happens. Why `VisualDesigner.Configuration` is **at first loaded successfully, but thereafter loading of this assembly causes failures**?

I also wonder why there is stated in logs that `Calling assembly : (Unknown).` in case of assembly binding failures?

Comment: By taking advantage of trial-and-error method, I have found that above problem is caused by custom `TypeConverter` class, defined in `VisualDesigner.Configuration` project, and then used in the same project as attribute of member within class that is derived from `ConfigurationElementCollection`: .`[TypeConverter(typeof(MyCustomTypeConverter))]`. `FileNotFoundException` is thrown at `System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeImpl(String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)`, by `Type.GetType(String, bool)` method. If I remove `TypeConverter` annotation, the assembly is loaded successfully.

Comment: Why there is a problem with loading such a simple `TypeConverter` class?